# Separate docker-compose file for testing NestJS

Tags: docker, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I have got main docker-compose file like that:

```
services:
   main:
      container_name: main
      build:
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
         context: './backend/'
      ports:
         - '${APP_PORT}:3000'
      volumes:
         - './backend/src:/backend/src'
      depends_on:
         - mongo

   mongo:
      container_name: mongodb
      image: mongo
      ports:
         - '27017:27017'
      environment:
         ...
      volumes:
         - mongo-data:/data/db
volumes:
   mongo-data:
```

/backend/Dockerfile (root NestJS folder):

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /backend

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY src/ tsconfig*.json ./

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

As you can see, there is only **src** folder in my container, which is good and intended. However, I would like to create a separate container only for testing my application, so instead of just the "src" folder I have to include the "tests" folder as well (or only tests folder and use src folder of this container?). Apart from that, I would also like to run the "jest" command to run unit tests contained in folders in the src folder.
I have no idea how to do this. Can I share folders through multiple containers or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to change you Dockerfile to a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds) with a testing stage. 
Here I have added a *prod* and a *testing* stage as well as your original (*dev*) build stage.

```dockerfile
FROM node:14 as dev
WORKDIR /backend
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY src/ tsconfig*.json ./
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]

FROM dev as testing
COPY tests ./
ENV CI=true
RUN ["npn", "run", "test"]

FROM dev as prod
LABEL version="1.0" "com.example.image"="My Image"
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

The you can [specify the build target](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#target) you want [with a variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) in your docker-compose-file.

```yaml
    services:
       main:
          container_name: main
          build:
             dockerfile: Dockerfile
             context: './backend/'
             target: ${TARGET:-prod}
          ports:
    ...
```

`TARGET` can be set in an `.env` file or by environment variable. I've set a default value so target becomes `prod` if not specified.

Other possible solutions would be to have multiple Dockerfiles or use a `docker-compose.override.yml` file with testing commands specified and different build context included.